# How to search in Marklogic Documents?

Tags: nosql, full-text-search, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am new to MarkLogic and I've inserted some json into its document db. How can I search or query on my documents?

Answer (score 2):

Have you read marklogic's documentation? I'd start [here](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev). They also have some beginner friendly and free videos online. I can recommend to start with the "[MarkLogic Fundamentals](https://www.marklogic.com/learn/courses/marklogic-fundamentals/)" course. Click "start self-paced training" if you want to watch them right away.